# EventKit created and make a defaultCalendar automatic

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im making for university a app using eventkit. i'm trying to create a calendar and make him like a "defaultCalendar , automatic", to add and read all events only on this calendar.

My code to try to make this is :

//im calling to make this code

EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

```
    EKSource *localSource = nil;
    for (EKSource *source in store.sources)
        if (source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeLocal){
            localSource = source;
            break;
        }

    EKCalendar *cal;
    cal = [EKCalendar calendarWithEventStore:store];

    cal.title = @"NewCalendar";
    cal.source = localSource;
    [store saveCalendar:cal commit:YES error:nil];


    //self.appDelegate.eventManager.selectedCalendarIdentifier = cal.calendarIdentifier;
    //  [cal.calendarIdentifier=cal.calendarIdentifier];


    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:cal.calendarIdentifier forKey:@"NewCalendar"];

}
```

}

So the question is how can i create this calendar and after only use this one on my app .
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create the calendar and store its identifier in NSUserDefaults. Once you have the identifier you can always use that calendar in your app. Your code already creates the calendar `cal`. From there, first, Make a key in NSUserDefaults so you can store its identifier

```
NSString *defaultCalendarIdentifier = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"defaultCalendarIdentifier"];
```

Then you can store the calendar identifier as the value of the key your just created.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: [eventStore cal].calendarIdentifier forKey:@"defaultCalendarIdentifier"];
```

NSUserDefaults will save the calendar id, even after the user closes and reopens the app.

When you create and read events from that calendar, always do it with the calendar id you just stored.

```
EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
//get default Calendar Identifier
NSString *defaultCalendarIdentifier = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                        stringForKey:@"defaultCalendarIdentifier"];
event.calendar = [eventStore calendarWithIdentifier:defaultCalendarIdentifier
```

This is basically how you create a calendar and use it in your app.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer :)